# NameError: global name 'Recipe' is not defined

Tags: python

I am new to python programming and currently I am creating a recipe program. I can't figure out how to get rid of this error.
The error says to define "Recipe" but I'm not sure what to do.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/2.Recipe/new.py", line 164, in <module>
    startup()
  File "E://2.Recipe/new.py", line 159, in startup
    recipe = Recipe()
NameError: global name 'Recipe' is not defined
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!
My code is:

```
    import os

mypath = "C:/Python33/Stuff/recipe"


class Ingredient():
    name = ""
    quantity = 0
    unit = ""


    def _init_(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.quantity = ""
        self.unit = ""


    def inputIngredientline(self):
        self.name = input("The ingredient name: ")
        if len(self.name)>0:
            self.unit = input("the unit of measurement: ")
            self.quantity = input("the quantity required: ")

    def ingredientLine(self):
        return self.quantity + "#" + self.unit + "#" + self.name + "#"

    def readIngredientLine(self, ingredientLine):
        hashTag1 = -1
        hashTag2 = -1
        hashTag3 = -1
        charIndex = 0

        noChar = len(self.ingredientLine())

        if noChar > 0:
            while charIndex0:
                self.file = open(mypath + "/" + self.name + ".txt", "w")
                self.person = input("The number of person this recipy is for: ")
                self.file.writelines(self.person + "#" + self.name + "#" + "#")
                self.ingredientEntry()

    def readRecipeLine(self, recipeLine):
        hashTag1 = -1
        hashTag2 = -1
        hashTag3 = -1
        charIndex = 0
        noChar = len(recipeLine())

        if noChar > 0:
            while charIndex0:
                self.file.writelines(Ingredient.ingredientLine(self.ingredient))
                nextEntry = True
        else:self.file.close()
        nextEntry = False

    def ingredientList(self, fileName):
        self.file = open(mypath + "/" + fileName, "r")
        firstLine = True
        for line in self.file:
            if firstLine:
                Recipe.readRecipeLine(self, line)
                firstLine = False
            else:
                if len(line)>0:
                    ingredient = Ingredient()
                    Ingredient.readIngredientLine(ingredient, line)
                    self.ingredients.append(ingredient)
                    self.file.close()

def outputRecipeForX(self, xperson):
    print("")
    print("")
    print("For " + self.name + " for " + str(xperson) + " persons you will need: ")
    ratio = (int(xperson)/int(self.person))
    for ingredient in self.ingredients:
          if len(ingredient.quantity)>0:
              quantity = int(ingredient.quantity)
              print (" --> " + ingredient.name + ": " + str(quantity) + " " + ingredient.unit)

class RecipeFile():
          filename = ""
          fileIndex = 0

def _init_(self):
          self.filename = ""
          self.fileIndex = 0

def toString(self):
          return str(self.fileIndex) + " " + self.filename

def chooseRecipe():
    recipeFile = RecipeFile()
    f = [RecipeFile()]
    i = 0
    default = 0
    noChoice = True
    for (dirpath, dirname, filenames) in os.walk(mypath):
        for filename in filenames:
            recipeFile = RecipeFile()
            recipeFile.filename = filename
            recipeFile.fileIndex = i
            if i==0:
                f = [recipeFile]
            else:
                f.append(recipeFile)
                i = i + 1
                for oneFile in f:
                    print (RecipeFile.toString(oneFile))
    while noChoice:
        choice = input("Enter the number of the recipe you wish to view: ").lower()
        if choice == "":
            noChoice = True
        elif int(choice) < (len(f)):
            recipeFile = f[int(choice)]
            noChoice = False
        else:
            error = "Please respond with a number between 0 and %i." % ((len(f)-1))
            print (error)
    return (recipeFile.filename)


def chooseNbPersons():
    people = 0
    default = 2
    noChoice = True
    while noChoice:
        choice = input("Enter the number of persons for the recipe (default 2): ")
        if choice == "":
            people = int(default)
            noChoice = False
        elif choice.isdigit():
            people = int(choice)
            noChoice = False
        else:
            error = "Please respond with a number."
            print (error)
            noChoice = True
            return people

def chooseMode():
    valid = {"New":True, "N":True, "new":True, "n":True, "View":False, "V":False, "view":False, "v":False}
    default = "View"
    while True:
        choice = input("Do you want to enter a new Recipe or view an existing one? (new/view)").lower()
        if choice == "":
            return valid[default]
        elif choice in valid:
            return valid[choice]
        else:
            print("Please respond with 'new' or 'view' (or 'n' or 'v').")

def startup():
    recipeFileName = ""
    if chooseMode():
        recipe = Recipe
        recipe.createRecipe(recipe)
    else:
        recipe = Recipe()
        recipeFileName = chooseRecipe()
        recipe.ingredientList(recipeFileName)
        recipe.outputRecipeForX(chooseNbPersons)

startup()
```

Comment: Where are you defining the variable `Recipe` for calling in program as `recipe = Recipe()`?

Comment: Is this the entirety of the code you're running? It looks like `Recipe` is a class which has not been defined.

Comment: Well, where *is* the definition of (the class) `Recipe`? Also (as a style hint), instead of of calling the class method `Recipe.ingredientList(recipe, recipeFileName)` you would usually call the instance method `recipe.ingredientList(recipeFileName)`.

Answer (score 0):

You see how you have classes called `Ingredient` and `RecipeFile`? Those, like the functions you have defined, are defined. Things which don't exist (you didn't create them or import them) are undefined. It looks like you meant to define a class called `Recipe`. You should do that.

Comment: I did define the class by doing 'recipe= Recipe()' like I did for 'Ingredient' and 'RecipeFile' yet the error still persists!

Comment: nowhere in your code is there a statement that says class Recipe ..... when you do recipe = Recipe() that is defining a name "recipe" which refers to an instance of the Recipe class - but the Recipe Class is not defined - hence the error.